# How can I speed up using a ternary operator?

Tags: ruby, optimization, ternary

I am attempting to answer a challenge question about coordinates within 100ms response time. I am given the following values through `STDIN` and am told to respond with a direction (`"NE"`, `"W"`, etc).

```
@light_x, @light_y, @initial_tx, @initial_ty = gets.split(" ").collect {|x| x.to_i}
```

I am trying to figure out why this attempt times out:

```
print @light_y > @initial_ty ? "S" : "N" unless @light_y == @initial_ty
print @light_x > @initial_tx ? "E" : "W" unless @light_x == @initial_tx
```

while this attempt does not:

```
if @light_x > @initial_tx && @light_y > @initial_ty
    puts "SE"
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx && @light_y > @initial_ty
    puts "SW"
elsif @light_x > @initial_tx && @light_y < @initial_ty
    puts "NE"
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx && @light_y < @initial_ty
    puts "NW"
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx && @light_y == @initial_ty
    puts "W"
elsif @light_x > @initial_tx && @light_y == @initial_ty
    puts "E" 
elsif @light_y > @initial_ty && @light_x == @initial_tx
    puts "S" 
elsif @light_y < @initial_ty && @light_x == @initial_tx
    puts "N"
else
end
```

Is there any way to speed up my ternary, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: It's because you're using print instead of puts on the first code block. Enjoying codeingame.com?

Comment: could you post a sample of the input? I'm suspecting it's because of the unless keywords. Not sure though

Comment: Did you benchmark what part of your code is actually too slow? `split`, `collect`, the conditionals or the output?

Comment: Attempting to combine a ternary with a postfix conditional might not be the best idea you've ever had. Very difficult to read and it is unlikely that a ternary or postfix is going to be any faster than an if-elsif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary issue isn't speed, it's clarity of the logic. I'd rewrite these:

```
print @light_y > @initial_ty ? "S" : "N" unless @light_y == @initial_ty
print @light_x > @initial_tx ? "E" : "W" unless @light_x == @initial_tx
```

to:

```
if @light_y > @initial_ty
  print 'S'
elsif @light_y < @initial_ty
  print 'N'
end

if @light_x > @initial_tx
  print 'E'
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx
  print 'W'
end
```

A ternary statement is only appropriate when there are two possible conditions, typically the result of a true/false condition or test result. You've got three conditions: `<`, `>` and `==` and you only want to output for the first two, resulting in logic that doesn't flow and is confusing.

Similarly, I think you can reduce this:

```
if @light_x > @initial_tx && @light_y > @initial_ty
  puts "SE"
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx && @light_y > @initial_ty
  puts "SW"
elsif @light_x > @initial_tx && @light_y < @initial_ty
  puts "NE"
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx && @light_y < @initial_ty
  puts "NW"
elsif @light_x < @initial_tx && @light_y == @initial_ty
  puts "W"
elsif @light_x > @initial_tx && @light_y == @initial_ty
  puts "E" 
elsif @light_y > @initial_ty && @light_x == @initial_tx
  puts "S" 
elsif @light_y < @initial_ty && @light_x == @initial_tx
  puts "N"
else
end
```

to:

```
y_direction = if @light_y > @initial_ty
                'S'
              elsif @light_y < @initial_ty
                'N'
              else
                ''
              end

x_direction = if @light_x > @initial_tx
                'E'
              elsif @light_x < @initial_tx
                'W'
              else
                ''
              end

puts y_direction + x_direction
```

That's all untested, but it looks about right.

The changes to the code *should* run faster because the code is reduced to fewer tests. It's also easier to understand, which your future self will appreciate.

Finally:

```
gets.split(" ")
```

can be written as:

```
gets.split
```

since the default behavior is to split on whitespace.

Comment: Good idea to separate the two directions. For fun, you could write `y_direction = ['', 'S', 'N'][@light_y <=> @initial_ty]`.

Comment: Yes, but it'd need to be documented because the behavior isn't intuitive. `y_direction = ['N', '', 'S'][(@light_y <=> @initial_ty) + 1]` would be almost as fast, and is a little more intuitive, but still would take a second to work out and could lead to additional errors being injected.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it clearer to use `case` statements rather than `if/elsif/else/end` constructs, and return the direction, to be printed outside the method. As general practice, it's often best to print return values of methods, rather than printing within the method, as it makes the method more versatile.

This implementation makes use of the *comparison* method `<=>` (e.g., [Fixnum#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), [String#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html), [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), and so on, depending on the class to which the arguments of `direction` belong.

```
def direction(light_x, light_y, init_tx, init_ty)
  case light_x <=> init_tx
  when -1   # light_x < init_tx
    case light_y <=> init_ty
    when -1 then "NW"
    when  0 then "W"
    when  1 then "SW"
    end
  when 0    # light_x = init_tx
    case light_y <=> init_ty  
    when -1 then "N"
    when  1 then "S"
    end
  when 1    # light_x > init_tx
    case light_y <=> init_ty
    when -1 then "NE"
    when  0 then "E"
    when  1 then "SE"
    end
  end
end

puts direction(3,2,1,1)
# SE
puts direction(1,2,1,1)
# S
puts direction(1,2,3,4)
# NW
```

Another option is use use a hash.

```
h = { [-1,-1]=>"NW", [-1,0]=>"W", [-1,1]=>"SW",
      [ 0,-1]=>"N",  [ 0,1]=>"S",
      [ 1,-1]=>"NE", [ 1,0]=>"E", [ 1,1]=>"SE" }

light_x, light_y, init_tx, init_ty = 3, 2, 1, 1
puts h[[light_x<=>init_tx, light_y<=>init_ty]]
# SE
light_x, light_y, init_tx, init_ty = 1, 2, 1, 1
puts h[[light_x<=>init_tx, light_y<=>init_ty]]
# S
light_x, light_y, init_tx, init_ty = 1, 2, 3, 4
puts h[[light_x<=>init_tx, light_y<=>init_ty]]
# NW
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `puts` instead of `print` here

```
print @light_y > @initial_ty ? "S" : "N" unless @light_y == @initial_ty
print @light_x > @initial_tx ? "E" : "W" unless @light_x == @initial_tx
```

Comment: That is what I originally thought may be the issue, but the output has to be on the same line. That is why I originally chose to use print. NOTE: puts does not work because of the sameline issue